# UILabel and UIButton coming as nil in all uiviewcontroller subclasses swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I'm trying to create a header which is common for all UIViewControllers. So i have created a ParentViewController class sub classed from UIViewController which is having one UIButton and UILabel in header view.

And I have created a subclass ChildViewController from ParentViewController class. But in ChildViewController UIButton and UILabel are coming as nil.

I have created UIButton and UILabel in storyboard and connected outlet too.
Also I have changed ChildViewController super class to ParentViewController in storyboard. I'm struck.

I'm using below code.

Parent view controller

```
import UIKit
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var viewTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton : UIButton!
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Child view controller

```
import UIKit
class ChildViewController: ParentViewController {
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.viewTitle.text = "String"
}
}
```

viewTitle coming as nil.
it's giving ("init(coder:) has not been implemented") error. can anyone help me?

Comment: Any specific reason as to why you are using `init()` while inheriting from `UIViewController`?

Comment: Just want to initialize the nib file. Because I have added UIButton and UILabel in ParentViewController storyboard file. These objects i have to use  it in all sub classes.

Comment: Try by removing `weak` property from IBOutlet

Comment: Try declaring the `@IBOutlet`s and `ParentViewController` as `public`